# what would happen if port 22 and 23 are opened

Tags: network, penetration-test

what would happen if port 22 and 23 are opened

Comment: Ports don't have vulnerabilities. Applications bound to ports can have vulnerabilities, or protocols operating on a specific port can have vulnerabilities. Step 1 is identifying what is actually running on the ports, then look at vulnerabilities associated with that package or protocol.

Comment: Welcome to [security.se] Benz! Unfortunately, as it stands this question is far too broad for us to answer and thus I have flagged the question for attention. It would greatly help us and yourself if you could edit to include a specific problem you're facing. Viewing the [Help Center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) will help you better understand the nature of the site and what questions you *can* ask - then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on what is listening on that ports.

However, just having the ports open mean that an attacker can interact with the TCP/IP stack of your machine.

Comment: I fail to see why the TCP/IP stack wouldn't just discard a packet on an unbound port.

Comment: I was doing information gathering with Nmap and did port scanning for an IP related to my application . The result displays that TCP port 23 was opened and several other ports . I was trying to figure out what would happen if these ports are open like DOS attacks can happen or Sniffing packets . I might be wrong Please correct me as I'm new to Network Pen Testing .

Comment: @M'vy What I understand is that that "discard" functionality means doing something with the packet, some kind of logic that finish with the TCP/IP Stack sending a RST, sending nothing or whatever. That "something" may have vulnerabilities. Not sure if I'm right and if this ever happened but I would like to listen other opinions.